# Does Heidegger (or Blanchot?) reflect on the form of the question itself?

Tags: metaphysics, ontology, heidegger, methodology

I have this notion that Heidegger is the first person to think about the framing of the question as a mode of inquiry. That is, to approach something as a question is to be already decided that a thing (and can we even say "thing" here?) is undecidable in some way. But that's to approach something as a question, which I take to be different than approaching something in the form of a what is? sort of question, or a particular type of question, since the what is? mode of inquiry presupposes that something is an object with properties.

This has to be Heidegger, right? and do we know how this relates to Blanchot?

I mean, there's the QUESTION concerning technology, where he presumably approaching technology as a question. But then he also asks WHAT IS thinking, so that's confusing.